# Having trouble rendering youtube search data using handlebars.js

Tags: backbone.js, youtube, handlebars.js

Im using the youtube data API and would like to template out my video search results but at the moment I'm a little confused about the paths to render out each piece of data, my data structure is, btw I'm using Backbone and parsing the response to return `response.items`.

**Data**
[image]

**And my template looks like this:**

```
<div class="video" title="{{snippet.title}}" id="{{id.videoId}}">
    <img class="video-image" src="{{snippet.thumbnails.default.url}}">
    <p class="video-title">{{snippet.title}}</p>
    <p class="video-author">{{snippet.channelId}}</p>
    <p class="video-description">{{snippet.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Also is this the correct type of search result data? How can I get likes/dislikes etc?

Comment: show more code and what have you tried to achieve what exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're having trouble getting the template to correctly render your data?  If so:

The data you get back in `response.items` is an array, so you'll have to loop over them in the template.

Modify your template like this:

```
{{each results}}
<div class="video" title="{{snippet.title}}" id="{{id.videoId}}">
    <img class="video-image" src="{{snippet.thumbnails.default.url}}">
    <p class="video-title">{{snippet.title}}</p>
    <p class="video-author">{{snippet.channelId}}</p>
    <p class="video-description">{{snippet.description}}</p>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Assuming you've compiled the Handlebars template into a variable called `template`, you can do this:

```
var context = {
   results: response.items
};
var html = template(context);
```

Notice that the `context` object has a `results` property, which is the array that gets looped over with the `{{each results}}`.

Since you're using Backbone, you'll probably want to update the view with
`this.$el.html(html);`. Don't forget to `return this;` from the `render` method too!

---

As far as the type of search results data, I don't know if that's the right or wrong results...that's up to you.  What kind of results do you want?  Is the data you're getting what you're looking for?

If you want Likes/Dislikes, you have to look that up on a per-video basis.  Register your application for the YouTube v3 API, and perform a `GET` request to the Videos resource ([API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#Videos)).  This will return a list of matching Videos ([Video resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)), which have a `likecount` and `dislikecount`.